# \makeglossaries not deterministic

Tags: glossaries

`glossaries` does not render items deterministically which are only referred to using `see` when not using `\loadglsentries`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
\newglossaryentry {call leg} {
  name={call leg},
  see={dialog},
  description={\nopostdesc}
}
\newglossaryentry {dialog} {
  name={SIP dialog},
  text={dialog},
  description={is an end-to-end relationship between two UA}
}

\printglossaries
\gls{dialog}

\end{document}
```

Now execute:

```
$ pdflatex test.tex
$ makeglossaries test
$ pdflatex test.tex
```

At this point the output looks like as it should:

[image: Correct output]

But after executing

```
$ makeglossaries test
$ pdflatex test.tex
```

...the "call leg" glossary entry disappeared:

[image: Missing "see" entry]

Is this a bug in the `glossaries` package or didn't I use it correctly? When using `\loadglsentries` instead of directly putting `\newglossaryentry` into the document, the behaviour is as expected.

Comment: What happens if you define the entries before `\begin{document}`?

Comment: @cfr: If defining all entries before `\begin{document}` it seems to behave as expected as well. As simple as this solution might be I never thought about it. Nevertheless, is it *required* to define the entries before the document? If yes, there should be a warning or error if not doing so.

Comment: The documentation does make very clear that for everything to work well, entries should be defined in the preamble. In some cases, you can define them afterwards and stuff will work correctly, but some stuff will not work right and it is strongly recommended to put definitions in the preamble. The manual is quite explicit about this.

Comment: @cfr D'you want to convert your comment into an answer to get this off the unanswered list?

Comment: @NicolaTalbot OK. If you think my comment is enough, I'm happy to convert it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Defining all entries before `\begin{document}` solves the problem.

The package documentation very strongly recommends putting all definitions in the preamble, and makes very clear that for everything to work well, entries should be defined here.

In *some* cases, you can define entries afterwards and stuff will work correctly, but other stuff will not work right.

The manual really is quite explicit about this. That is, the documentation already provides clear warnings about the consequences of defining entries in the document body, often in the form of statements that certain things just won't work at all in this case.